# How to access array within object in template Handlebars & Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I'm trying to access the "name" attribute of the following JSON in a handlebars template, using ember.js and can't seem to get it to work.

I extend the model as follows:

```
    App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
      taxonomies : DS.attr();     
});
```

And my JSON looks like this:

```
{"taxonomies":{
    "positions":[
     {
        "name":"F",
     }
  ],
  "nhlteams":[
     {
        "name":"MTL",
     }
  ]
}}
```

In the template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts">
    <h1>Position Name: {{taxonomies.positions.0.name}}</h1>
    <h1>Team Name: {{taxonomies.nhlteams.0.name}}</h1>
</script>
```

I've also tried:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts">
    <h1>Position Name: {{taxonomies.positions.name}}</h1>
    <h1>Team Name: {{taxonomies.nhlteams.name}}</h1>
</script>
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `hasMany` relationship between `taxonimies` and `positions` etc

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  taxonomy: DS.belongsTo('taxonomy');     
});

App.Taxonomy = DS.Model.extend({
  positions : DS.hasMany('position');     
});

App.Position = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr()
});
```

Then your json would need to be in this format

```
{
  post:{
   taxonomy:1
  },
  taxonimies:[
    {
      id:1,
      positions:[1]
    }
  ],
  positions:[
    {
      id:1,
      name:"F"
    }
  ]
}
```

To see more info on how ember data is expecting the json, see https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: So in this scenario, how would you then call name via handlebars.js?

Comment: in this instance, assuming post is our current context, I'd do `{{taxonomy.positions.firstObject.name}}`